# Genetically Modified Human Super Leaders

Tags: science-based, biology, government, genetic-engineering

In my book set in the future, all of humanity has united under the leadership of a super race of genetically modified people called Overseers (numbering at least 1000) and has built a space (empire size) nation called The Human Collective.

The Overseers supervise all fields: Science, governance, military, education, health and so on. They live for a very long time and are very difficult to kill.

**What would be the most useful physical body design for the Overseers?**

Think about creating a recipe for a superhuman leader. What would you use or do to create a leader race? Genetic treatment? Chimaeras? I am open to suggestions!

Examples: I was thinking that they could have a new organ or core device that would either send in nanobots or specialized cells to repair the body in case of damage or fatigue.

Notes:

- I don't mind each Overseer being tailored specifically for their job.
- I don't want them to go down the robotics road.
- This is a body design question on what would they most likely use to make Overseers.
- Overseers do not have to be perfect beings (a big plot point is that they are flawed just like us but they are more like a guide for humanity to lead and serve the best they can).

Comment: if you want more info just let me know and i can provide more back story for you

Comment: Nobody knows how to make people significantly smarter. Statistically a little bit by giving them a decent education and maybe selective breeding, but ... We are just at the beginning of understanding our body and mind and have so far barely touched the surface. Let's not talk about the methods used by the people studying the field, but progress is slow and will continue to be slow. This is good news for you because it means you don't even have to explain it in a book. It is so far out of reach to modify a human in such a way that you can basically just say "genetically altered to be that way".

Comment: What do you mean by "build such a race?".

Comment: What do you mean when you say "best way"? Very few people will provide ideas that they feel aren't good, but it's generally better to provide objective criteria by which suggestions can be judged. Also, what do you mean by "smarter"? Able to retain more knowledge internally? (Hint; pretty much since the dawn of written language, that has become less and less important.) Able to do calculations in their heads? (Hint; computers are probably better at that than any living organism can ever be.) Or what?

Comment: what i was asking is what would be the most useful way of deigning a race like this, like the ideas i stated IF we could do it how would we do it and i know that computers can be better then humans but no one would rally behind a computer telling them what to do, the overseers are more like a shepherd then an all knowing god

Comment: I'm not sure what's the actual question here. "most useful way" for whom? In what environment? What are they going to be used for, exactly?..

Comment: and sorry for not being more clear

Comment: We all start out somewhere. However, you may want to use [the question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/29) next time, to get early feedback before posting your question on the main site.

Comment: good tip did not know that was there thank you

Comment: This question has been edited and therefore automatically entered into the reopen queue.  It's not ready.  It's also impossible to answer.  We don't have the technology to create [Khan Noonien Singh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khan_Noonien_Singh) today, and yet you want hard-science for how to do it.  As I was once told by another: if I had an answer to that, I wouldn't post it here, I'd be on my way to the patent office.  As it stands the question is primarily opinion-based and impossible to answer.  I cannot vote to reopen it.

Comment: So JBH i would like to point a few things out for you. One: i never said with today's technology (i did point out it was a space nation) but i will add it is in the future for you. two: i did state that the answers can be open minded (no wrong answers) its more for brain storming then 100% right i know that the tech can’t happen yet. i am sorry for using the tag hard-science, i will get rid of it now. So i would hope that you can put my question back I’m just here for info for my book and to see what smart people can come up with to answer them

Comment: @CreedArcon If it is "for brain storming", then it is almost by definition primarily opinion-based, which is a reason to put a question on hold. We require that questions can have specific answers. You may want to review [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in the [help]. If you want to participate in discussion rather than Q&A, then by now you have enough reputation to talk in [chat], where there's usually some people hanging out.

Answer (score 2):

Our current ability to alter the DNA of humans and other organisms is actually quite advanced. With enough time and money we can create virtually any DNA sequence you can desire, be it completely novel or spliced together components from other organisms, and we can incorporate these changes into embryos to produce living beings.

So what’s holding us back? We don’t know *what* to change. We can edit the DNA however we’d like, but we have no idea what it will do. Much of current research in many fields throughout biology is tinkering with DNA to see what happens. Delete that section, move that other part over here, add in this thing and write down what happens. In this way we slowly, bit-by-bit, learn what we can about how life works.

So the answer to your question of how we would make the changes is relatively straightforward. Just use existing technology or whatever future equivalents exist to alter the DNA in the desired way. Your question of what we should change to produce the desired traits is however impossible to answer. We simply have no idea how to make humans smarter or increase their lifespans. If we did, we’d be doing it right now.

Comment: indeed useful, i know i was asking for an impossible answer but i was asking for a more roundabout way to achieve this (not a yes or no)  like your DNA answer was useful, anymore answers like this will be most helpful